# A simple pi simulation in Haskell - using replicateM

Tags: haskell

I am working on writing a simple pi simulation in Haskell, and I was wondering if there was a way of doing so using replicateM and without using one of the packages mentionning in the following two articles :

http://ptrckprry.com/blog/programming/2008/08/26/a-monte-carlo-monad-for-haskell/

https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/03/monte-carlo-haskell

If there exists a simple simulation of pi written in Haskell, I would like to hear about it - I've tried searching on GitHub as well.

----- EDIT ------

I tried to rewrite the unitBox part of Patrick Perry's example, but I am an error regarding the use of liftM2. Am I mal-interpreting how to use liftM2 or is it with random_2p ? I am really new to all of this and it is hard to see where I am making a mistake.

Here is my code :

```
import Numeric.GSL.Distribution.Continuous
import Control.Monad

unitbox :: (Double,Double)
unitbox = liftM2 (,) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)
                     (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)
```

And is the error message :

```
Prelude Numeric.GSL.Distribution.Continuous> :l unitBox.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( unitBox.hs, interpreted )

unitBox.hs:5:18:
    Couldn't match type ‘(a10, a20)’ with ‘Double’
    Expected type: a10 -> a20 -> Double
      Actual type: a10 -> a20 -> (a10, a20)
    In the first argument of ‘liftM2’, namely ‘(,)’
    In the expression:
      liftM2 (,) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)

unitBox.hs:5:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘(Double, a10)’
                with actual type ‘Double’
    In the second argument of ‘liftM2’, namely
      ‘(random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)’
    In the expression:
      liftM2 (,) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)

unitBox.hs:6:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘(Double, a20)’
                with actual type ‘Double’
    In the third argument of ‘liftM2’, namely
      ‘(random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)’
    In the expression:
      liftM2 (,) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1) (random_2p Uniform 0 0 1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Sadly, I am still enough of a beginner that I was unable to actually try anything. Hence the reason why I was looking for a workable example to help me grasp certain concepts.

Comment: Both the pages you linked have complete, executable examples. If you have problems with working on them, please tell us what your exact problems are. Start trying.

Comment: I did my best to try something. See my edit : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of [`random_2p`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hstatistics-0.1.0.4/docs/Numeric-GSL-Distribution-Continuous.html#v:random_2p) is `Double` and not `m Double` where `m` would be a Monad. As a consequence, you don't need to `liftM2` the pair constructor.

If you look [under the hood](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hstatistics-0.1.0.4/docs/src/Numeric-GSL-Distribution-Continuous.html#random_2p), all these functions use `unsafePerformIO` so they are indeed effectful but presented as pure for some reason. It is quite unidiomatic to do so. I don't know this library but this is a bit of red flag for me.